# How to get url of images which is saved in firebase storage into variable using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-storage

I used the following code to upload the image in storage

```
var filename = selectedfile.name;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/driverimages/'+filename);
var uploadtask = storageRef.put(selectedfile);
```

I need to get saved image url to laravel php variable. I used the following code for that. But it's not working. How can I do that?

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded

}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  // uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    downloadURL = uploadtask.snapshot.downloadURL.toString();
    console.log(downloadURL);                

  });
```

Comment: You have the proper code in comments: `uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL)`. Expand that to `uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) { console.log(downloadURL); })` and you'll get the correct URL.